# How do I hide a checkbox label?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms

I have an ASP.NET checkbox and I'm using the .Text property to store a value. How do I hide the checkbox's text (label)? I'm using the .Text property for "hidden" storage of a single value.

Comment: you probably want to use attribute instead of the `Text` property

Answer (score 3):

Checkboxes aren't designed to store hidden values. Use a [HiddenField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a hidden field, it's worth mentioning that the data will travel to the user along with the rest of the page. A more advanced user can modify this data then.

If you want to store a value between page loads and don't want the user to be able to modify it, you can use [***session state***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom attribute prefaced with "data-" to be HTML5 compliant.

```
 <asp:CheckBox id="myCheckbox" data-ID='X' runat='server' />
```

EDIT:
You're probably wanting to do this from code-behind, though. Should be something like this (untested):

```
myCheckbox.InputAttributes.Add("data-ID", "X");
```